# Преобразование Фурье в MATLAB

Tags: matlab, фурье

Подскажите, пожалуйста, относительно Фурье преобразования в среде MATLAB. Сам 3-й день пытаюсь понять через гугл и периодические журналы...
Есть набор ЭЭГ-сигналов: 500 значений за 2 сек (частота 250 Гц). Мне надо просто разложить их в спектр (насколько понимаю от 0 до 125) и получить
значения 2-х полос: от 0.5 до 14 Гц и от 14 до 40 Гц. Но даже разложение в спектр, полагаю с ошибкой:

```
% init
fs = 250;

% load
da = da1_all;
x = da(1:256,1);

% Построение графика спектральной плотности
fx = fft(x);
sfx = fftshift(fx);
f = linspace(-fs/2,fs/2,length(x));
area(f,abs(sfx));
title('Амплитудный спектр сигнала');
xlabel('Частота(Гц)');
ylabel('Амплитуда');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ``x = da(1:256,1);`` - почему здесь используется только половина данных?

Comment: Как я понял, должна быть степень 2ки: для 512 не хватает, поэтому 256.

Comment: 1. Не должна. 2. Если вам нужно получить спектр трехминутной песни с диска, вы же не будете брать из неё для анализа только первые 30 секунд. А примерно это вы здесь и делаете.